# Chatbot connection in PowerApps

Tags: chatbot, powerapps

I have already created the QNA, Postman and the connection but I'm stuck in the app, can anyone help me on this ?

I'm using the below code-

**for onselect of the button**

```
Collect(chat,{id:1,name:User().FullName,text:TextInput1.Text});
Collect(chat,{id:0,name:"EmployeeFaqBot",text:First(OPMS_Service.GenerateAnswer("a6*****7c","application/json",{question:TextInput1.Text}).answers).answer})
```

**OnStart of the screen**

```
ClearCollect(chat,{id:0,name:"EmployeeFaqBot",text:"Welcome " &User().FullName &" ! Enter your Query"})
```

**Error -**

"Invalid number of arguments" on OnSelect of the button.

**I've tried below codes as well**

```
Collect(chat,{id:1,name:User().FullName,text:TextInput1.Text});
Collect(chat,{id:0,name:"EmployeeFaqBot",text:First(OPMS_Service.GenerateAnswer({question:TextInput1.Text}).answers).answer})


Collect(chat,{id:1,name:User().FullName,text:TextInput1.Text});
Collect(chat,{id:0,name:"EmployeeFaqBot",text:First(OPMS_Service.GenerateAnswer("application/json",{question:TextInput1.Text}).answers).answer})


Collect(chat,{id:1,name:User().FullName,text:TextInput1.Text});
Collect(chat,{id:0,name:"EmployeeFaqBot",text:First(OPMS_Service.GenerateAnswer({"application/json",question:TextInput1.Text}).answers).answer})
```

Thanks.